# How to localize an ErrorMessage found in ValidationResult?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, entity-framework-6

I have a class called `EFErrors` which practically has a list of errors which might occur at `context.SaveChanges()`...So it is defined like this:

```
private List<ValidationResult> _errors;
```

And I am filling it with errors with something like this:

```
public EFErrors ValidateAndSave(){
     var status = new EFErrors();

      try
      {
          this._context.SaveChanges(); 
       }
          catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
       {
           return status.SetErrors(ex.EntityValidationErrors);

       }
 }
```

Now ValidationResult instance has a property called ErrorName... So for example when I get an error like this:

> "The field username must be a string or array type with a
>   maximum length of '30'."

I want to show this error back to the user, using error provider (or something similar), but he doesn't really have to know about all the specifics (which are useful for me as a programmer). I just want to point out what is important eg. 30 characters at max, allowed characters etc without for example mentioning a real column name like in a quoted text above. And I want to provide a translation, which is the main goal here.

I guess I should use a resource file...But I couldn't find what else I have to set up to localize errors.

And here is a declaration of `SetErrors` method on `EFErrors` class if that matters:

```
public EFErrors SetErrors(IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> errors)
{
      _errors =
          errors.SelectMany(
                x => x.ValidationErrors.Select(y =>
                        new ValidationResult(y.ErrorMessage, new[] { y.PropertyName })))
         .ToList();
     return this;
}
public EFErrors SetErrors(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> errors)
{
  _errors = errors.ToList();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: i think you need [.Net Framwork language pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23067)

Comment: Now this is certainly useful, thanks! But not in my case actually. I want my own translations ... Not the literal translations... Or I am missing your point? @Hadi

Comment: I am afraid that the second method is somehow painful, since you don't know which properties will fire the error from database side, but in all cases, there are plenty of approaches, what I practice is to avoid the `DbEntityValidationException` and I use `Resources`, in this case, you need to add the errors to the resources one by one and if you forgot any uncaught error, you might later need to update your code